# Handling Variable Amount (Donation) With Stripe & PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to allow users to enter custom amounts using Stripe. They enter what they want to pay in a input. Then I have a script that collects the amount below the default stripe checkout button. But how am I supposed to handle the charge server-side on `charge.php`?

**donation.php**

```
    //user enter custom amount
    <input type="number" class='form-control' 
    id="custom-donation-amount" 
    placeholder="$50.00" min="0" step="10.00 " />

    //default stripe checkout button
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        data-amount="0"
        data-name="ORGANIZATION"
        data-description="Saving Penguins"
        data-image="logo.png"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true"
        data-billing-address="true"
        data-label="DONATE"
        data-currency="usd">
      </script>

//script to collect variable amount
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.donate-button').click(function(event) {
            var amount = $('#custom-donation-amount').val();        
            $('.stripe-button').attr('data-amount', amount)
        });
    });
</script>
```

**charge.php**

```
<?php require_once('./config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'source'  => $token,
      'email' => $email)
  );

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

   header("Location: confirmation.php");
die();


?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within the `<form>` where you place Checkout, you'd also want to add an input to collect the Amount from the user. Note the name I've given my input a name of `amount`

```
<form method="POST" action="/charge.php">
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" id="custom-donation-amount" placeholder="50.00" min="0" step="10.00" />
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
data-name="ORGANIZATION"
data-description="Saving Penguins"
data-image="logo.png"
data-locale="auto"
data-billing-address="true"
data-label="DONATE"
data-currency="usd">
</script>
</form>
```

In your backend you could grab this `amount` field when Checkout submits, much like you would the token created by Stripe

```
$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

// your code to create a charge
// ...
```

If you're looking to dynamically change the amount displayed within the Checkout window, you should use the Custom Checkout, rather than the basic Checkout block, or it may not update correctly.

See 
https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Or, for a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/g2ufa8xr/

Comment: Is it possible to set up a stripe form that just collects the user input custom amount without trying to collect anything on a backend? I just want the jquery functionality as seen in the jsfiddle, but I just want that passed to stripe and that's it (for now until I get better versed at backend stuff)...

Comment: @DeltaFlyer you always need a backend! But it doesn't have to be much. You could use something like Heroku, AWS Lambda, a very small instance at any web host.